# Bootstrap YEAR PICKER to display random years according to our requirement

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

Am using bootstrap datepicker where I have options like Date Month Year for filtering purpose. Now while selecting the year my viewMode is "years" , displaying just the years decade wise. Now I need to display only specific years such as "2001" , "2006" and "2014" . How can I achieve this ?

```
               $('#fromYearPicker').datepicker({
                autoclose: true,
                format: " yyyy",
                viewMode: "years", 
                minViewMode: "years",
                startDate: '2001',
                endDate: new Date(),
            }).next().on("click", function() {
                $(this).prev().focus();
            });
            $("#fromYearPicker").datepicker("setDate", ' '+CurrentYear);

            $('#toYearPicker').datepicker({
                autoclose: true,
                format: " yyyy",
                viewMode: "years", 
                minViewMode: "years",
                startDate: '2001',
                endDate: new Date(),
            }).next().on("click", function() {
                $(this).prev().focus();
            });
            $("#toYearPicker").datepicker("setDate", ' '+CurrentYear);

<!-- YearPicker -->         
                    <div class="col-xs-4 credit-section yearDiv filtersDiv">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-xs-6"
                                style="padding-top: 0px; border-right: 1px solid #ddd;">
                                <label>From Year </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6" style="padding: 0px;">
                                <div class="col-xs-12" style="padding: 0px;">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fromYearPicker" />
                                    <div class="input-group-addon icon addon-fix">
                                        <i class="fa fa-calendar bigger-110"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 credit-section yearDiv filtersDiv">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-xs-6"
                                style="padding-top: 0px; border-right: 1px solid #ddd;">
                                <label>To Year </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6" style="padding: 0px;">
                                <div class="col-xs-12" style="padding: 0px;">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="toYearPicker" />
                                    <div class="input-group-addon icon addon-fix">
                                        <i class="fa fa-calendar bigger-110"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
        <!-- YearPicker -->
```

Comment: can you supply your HTML too please. Is there a pattern to the years you want displayed? ie. every 4 years from 2001. Do you want to hide all other years, or just disable them?

Comment: Pattern/format is yyyy and yes i wanna hide all the other years . @haxxxton have updated my question with HTML

Answer (score -1):

You can just visually hide options from year select range. Closest native option would be `yearRange` but it does not allow format like `2001,2006,2014`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').datepicker({
    yearRange: '2001:2016',
    changeYear: true
  });
  $('input').click(function() {
    $('#ui-datepicker-div')
        .find('.ui-datepicker-year option')
        .filter(function() {
            return $(this).val() !== '2001' && $(this).val() !== '2006' && $(this).val() !== '2014'
        })
        .hide();
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input />
```

Comment: perhaps `return ['2001','2006','2014'].indexOf($(this).val()) >= 0;` for easier editing of the list of years?

Comment: But on the second click , it displays all the years plus am using a datepicker like this - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jaa37.png